# Should I use Firebase anonymous login to secure my data?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Let's say I wanted to show some data to every user. Then I probably write the Cloud Firestore rule like below.

```
allow read: if true;
```

Is this really a security risk? If my intention is to show some data to every user then why do I need to sign in them anonymously and write my rule like below?

```
allow read: if request.auth != null;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Anonymous Authentication Enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60609593/is-anonymous-authentication-enough) This also has some steps you can take to tighten up your database to make it harder to abuse even if you don't add anonymous authentication. But this question is also asking for opinion-based answers, so it might get closed that way too.

Comment: I also wouldn't think of it as a "security risk", but instead a risk to your wallet. This could be in the form of a DDOS driving your costs up or accidentally giving read access to private data - breaching GDPR and ending up with a hefty fine.